# Next JS how to order the price of products using two buttons receiving data?

Tags: reactjs, button, next.js, fetch-api, use-effect

I want to create two buttons to sort an array from lowest price to highest price.
the data import is from data props, my handles sort only price the array but i want sort all items array

```js
function Products({ data }) {


    const productPrice = data.map(product => product.price)
   

    const [sortPrice, setSortPrice] = useState(productPrice)

    // I don't know what logic I have to use in the useEffect

    useEffect(() => {

        setSortPrice()
    }, [sortPrice])

    function handleHigh(e) {
        setSortPrice(
            productPrice.sort((a, b) => a - b)
        )
    }

    console.log(sortPrice)

    function handleLow(e) {
        setSortPrice(
            productPrice.sort((a, b) => b - a)
        )
    }
```

JSX Component

```
import React from 'react'
import styles from '../../styles/Filter.module.css'


export default function Filter({ handleHigh, handleLow }) {

    return (
        <div>
            <div className={styles.filter}>
                <button className={styles.btn1} onClick={handleHigh}>+</button>
                <button className={styles.btn2} onClick={handleLow}>-</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Hi.If you want to sort array when click button you dont need to use useEffect

Comment: Please show your JSx to show what buttons you have and how you are reneding the list

Comment: if I delete the useEffect it doesn't work.